# How to nullify empty output errors in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, regex

I am using the following code in many cells of the sheet,

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE("" & S2, "(\d)", "$1,"), ",")
```

not all are going to contain data at any one time. How do I stop the empty cell value notice from appearing?

Answer (score 0):

- try wrapping it into empty **`IFERROR`** function

  ```
  =IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(""&S2, "(\d)", "$1,"), ","))
  ```
- another way would be to use **`IF`** logic:

  ```
  =IF(LEN(S2), SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(""&S2, "(\d)", "$1,"), ","), )
  ```

Comment: Thanks for that worked a treat . Is there a way I can copy and drag down so my cell range changes as thus:    s4     t4    u4    v4  etc

Comment: `=IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(""&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(4, ROW($S19), 4)), "(\d)", "$1,"), ","))`

Comment: @Peteh if a provided answer solved your issue pls accept the answer